# How to find the name of an Oracle Sequence used by a column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

```
    class Foo(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'foo'
        id = Column(Integer, Sequence('foo_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
        bar = Column(String(10))
```

Is it possible to reflect the name of the the sequence `foo_id_seq` from `Foo.c` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `Foo.c` you mean an instance of Foo then:

```
f = Foo()
print(f.__table__.c['id'].default.name)
```

Comment: Sweet thanks; `Foo.__table__.c.id.default` and `Foo.id.default.name` also work.